# Finding coefficient of $x^k$ in summation of binomial series

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I am not able to solve this problem

Find the coefficient of $x^k\;\;(k$ is greater than or equal to zero and lesser than or equal to $n$) in the expansion of $E = 1 + (1+x) + (1+x)^2 .... + (1+x)^n$

The final simplified answer is $(n+1)C(k+1)$

Any help would be thoroughly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $E$ is just the sum of the [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series), $E=\dfrac{(1+x)^{n+1}-1}{x}$ and thus the coefficient of $x^k$ is ${n+1 \choose k+1}$

Comment: I am afraid I didn't understand your last step, sir. Can u pls elucidate?

Comment: user34304: sure- let me edit my answer
@AndréNicolas: Thanks- will edit it.

Comment: Nice answer, sir.